# stop checking for updates

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In sublime terminal (ctrl + `) every minute I got annoing lines:

```
Checking for updates:
    Sync Enabled: True
    Sync Timeout: 60000
    Latest Update at: Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
    Thread is: Thread-4
    Paths: [{'path': '', 'display': ''}]
```

It interrupt me from debuging sublime plugins.

How to disable this `Checking for updates`?

I tried 2 things to disable it:

1. I added line `"update_check": false` into `/Users/maks/Library/Application    Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`:

   {
       "ignored_packages":
       [
           "JavaScript Console",
           "Vintage"
       ],
       "update_check": false
   }

   And restarted sublime. But nothing...
2. I tried to find string `60000` in all files of sublime folder: `/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`
   But nothing good found. Maybe 60000 ms is default value.

**Update**

Created function to search text in packages and installed packages:

```
searchInSubl()
{
    cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Installed\ Packages; zgrep -e $1 *.sublime-package ; cd ../Packages; grep -R -e  $1 *
}
```

With help of it I searched by different words: "Checking for updates", "Sync Enabled", "Sync Timeout", "60000", "Latest Update at", "Thread is", "Paths". But nothing found.

Seemingly this update is internal `sublime 3` option. Don't know how to disable it...

Comment: Have ever installed any other plugins?

Comment: Yes I installed different plugins. `$ cd Installed\ Packages/
Makss-Mac:Installed Packages maks$ ls
4GL.sublime-package
All Autocomplete.sublime-package
Better CoffeeScript.sublime-package
BracketHighlighter.sublime-package
Clipboard Path.sublime-package
CoffeeCompile.sublime-package
CopyEdit.sublime-package
Delete Current File.sublime-package` and etc.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 doesn't like Sublime Text 2. The installed packages, for example, `Package Control.sublime-package`, is a ZIP file. So possibly you couldn't use `grep` to find a string in it directly. You need to unzip them before searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sublime Text 3 packages are in zipped `.sublime-package` files, you'll need to use [`zgrep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zgrep.1.html) to search them:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Installed\ Packages
zgrep -e "Checking for updates" *.sublime-package
```

If nothing is found, try looking in the `Packages` directory:

```
cd ../Packages
grep -R -e "Checking for updates" *
```

Hopefully one of these will match a package. If so, add the package to your `ignored_packages` setting and restart Sublime.

If neither search works, try using other fragments of the message as your search term: "*Sync Enabled*", "*Latest Update*", etc.

Good luck!

### Please Note:

This is not the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206), where setting `"update_check": false` in your user preferences does not stop Sublime Text 3 from displaying upgrade messages when a new build is released. This particular issue was caused by a plugin constantly printing a message to Sublime's console. As the OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656406/stop-checking-for-updates/20248188#comment30219407_20248188) below:

> using turning off and on every single plugin, target plugin found, its name: "My Snippets" in Installed Packages folder.

Comment: Text searching did not help. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, the other option is more time consuming, but necessary - put all of your packages in `ignored_packages` and verify that the unwanted behavior stops. Then, start removing them (re-activating them) one at a time until the messages start again.

Comment: using turning off and on every single plugin, target plugin found, its name: "My Snippets" in `Installed Packages` folder.

Answer (score 32):

My current version of sublime text 3 is 3083. Here how the guys solved it [HERE](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/disable-update-available-pop-up/1381/7).

### Text version

Go to Preferences -> Settings-User -> and paste that line of code in the end:

`"update_check": false,` or `"update_check": false` (without last comma if it's last item in the array). After that press `CTRL + S` (on Windows OS) to Save file or go to `File -> Save`

### Image version

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not working for me as of 3103, which is unfortunate because they managed to mangle my theme's syntax for a second time with 3114, and I'd love to ignore all updates forever.

Comment: @VaelVictus this option [has been broken](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206) since at least build 3080. A bug has been filed (see link) and presumably the devs are aware of it.

Comment: @mcs This does not answer the actual question being asked. OP is trying to disable a plugin that is constantly printing a message to the console. He is *not* trying to disable the upgrade dialog that is displayed when a new build of ST3 is released.

Comment: Works in build 3124

Comment: Works for me on build 3176. Thanks for your very clear answer, Matija.

Comment: FINALLY! Thank you! Works for me too on 3.2.2, 3211. I wanted to upgrade to V4 but can NOT afford that price (after already buying V3). Was so tired of seeing the new version message *every time I opened the app*!

Comment: It works if you enter a key license

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, depending on what exactly you want to accomplish.

Since I am not sure - possibly my English - so I give you two solutions.

**BLOCK PACKAGE FROM UPDATING**

I use Sublinter as an example.

```
Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – User
```

... and add something like this to block package:

```
// Packages to not auto upgrade
    "auto_upgrade_ignore": [
        "SublimeLinter"
    ],
```

**BLOCK SUBLIME FROM UPDATING**

If you want Sublime to stop updating and you do not trust in-app update blocking solutions, just nuke 'em.

On Windows (system I use) go to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

... and open file named 'hosts'.

You may have to move this file onto desktop, edit it and move it back to original location, as Windows may not allow any changes to it - even, if you try as Administrator.

Then add to 'hosts' file this line of code:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       www.sublimetext.com
127.0.0.1       localhost       sublimetext.com
```

Version with 'www' will do, as sublime sends updates from 'www.sublimetext.com' location.

Above code will prevent any connection from your machine to 'www.sublimetext.com', hence no updates anymore.

That does not apply to packages, they need option #1.

Comment: Worked for me. Other in-app solution didn't work, but nuking it in the hosts file did.